# Disable manual build trigger for jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to disable *manual build* trigger to be **configured per job**?

I explicitly do not want to disable a job, obviously, as it should be triggered by other build triggers (SCM Polling, Schedule, upstream job).

Comment: Using project-based security doesn't help as it behaves, unpredictably.  When disabling global inheritance (global permissions grant my user group to build jobs) and explicitly granting all permissions for the job to my user group, the job disappears anyway.  
With enabled global inheritance, defining my user group in the matrix and not enabling the *build* checkbox doesn't disable manual build ability (that's okay so far).

Answer (score 8):

Try using [Job Restrictions Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin)

Then check these options:

- Restrict build execution causes
- Restrict manual builds submission
- Prohibits manual launch of the job for all users

Although users can launch the Job, it will be immediately aborted with message in console:

> FATAL: [Job Restrictions] - Build will be aborted: Manual launch is
>   prohibited